# Copy data from Azure AD to vm AD?

Tags: active-directory, virtual-machines, azure, radius

Currently I only have Azure AD that work with Office 365. Now I am planning to create a vm to use RADIUS server. I need to copy user and groups from Azure AD to vm AD. So, how can I do that?

I read many articles and forums and only found the ways to sync from vm AD to Azure AD but not from Azure AD to vm AD.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do automatic sync from Azure AD back to AD. You have to do this yourself using Azure AD graph API